# Angular 2 building single modules

Tags: angular

I know how to build out my project with Angular CLI: `ng build --prod`

How can I compile each module separately? This is my project:

[image]

`AnagAccreditamento` and `cruscottofiliera` are separate modules, with their `module.ts`, `routing.module.ts` file. How I can build them separately and insert them into my project at a later time as if they were libraries?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to compile modules independently. For example tree-shaking can only work if the whole application is compiled at once. Otherwise it's never known what code is or is not in used and can be dropped.

Comment: if I create a folder with a module and my colleague creates another folder with another module. We are forced to copy all the modules within the same project and then compile them? Angular should not be modular?

Comment: Yes. Angular is most often used as a browser-based framework. So *all* of the pieces needed (including external packages) are all in the same project.

Comment: If you want to build a library that is installable from npm (for example), you could do that ... but you'd still need to have it in your project in the node_modules folder.

Comment: I agree that all the pieces have to be in the same project (in the build, production folder). 
I would not want to have that at "compile time", for al workers, all the pieces must be in the same project

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about angular2 but you 'could'(!) definitely do this with angular 10. Not sure if it's the right way to do it (or if further separation would be a good idea).

To achieve building multiple modules out of a single project:

1. You obviously need multiple modules. So not only `app.module.ts`but another one that contains similar model configuration stuff, i.e. called `app-extension.module.ts`.
2. Accordingly you'll need another `main.ts` file, referencing the module. I.e. called `main-extension.ts`. You import the specific module there and bootstrap it.
3. Same for `tsconfig.app.json` -> `tsconfig.app-extension.json`
4. Next, in your `angular.json` file, you can extend the project -> architect -> build section by adding something like this:

   ```
      "configurations": {
        "extension": {
          "main": "src/main-extension.ts",
          "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app-extension.json",
          "outputPath": "../resources/public/extension"
        }
   ```
5. finally within your `package.json` you add a new script

   ```
        "build:extension": "ng build && ng build --output-hashing none --configuration extension "
   ```

   the --output-hashing none is not really relevant here. I did this for building a custom elements-module / webcomponents for standalone use, so that's why i left it in here. Next step would be to concatenate. A better alternative probably is to use https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus#readme for that purpose..

to build *simply* execute `npm run build:extension`

Comment: Great answer this helped me a lot, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to pull in modules as they are needed, you want lazy loading. You can find out how to use lazy loading here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#asynchronous-routing

Or there is a Pluralsight course about it here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need to dynamically load modules. 
I would like to have the same behavior that I had with SystemJS configuration, where was enough to change the file.js of the module / component that I wanted to update. Now with WebPach configuration, AoT, ... I can not interact with the individual components of the application.